# Wordpress Url Rewrite and replace

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

i am trying to change the wordpress url with htaccess, i have the following scenario

My url will look like this, this will be visible to users.
http://www.example.com/custom-field-name1/custom-field2/post-name

While the actual url is this one
http://www.example.com/post-type-name/post-name.

Please help me how this will be possible with htaccess

Comment: Why do you need to do this via htaccess? Wordpress has its own setting to customize permalinks, maybe you can explain why you need to do it with htaccess.

Comment: Ok, but how it would be possible by customizing permalinks,  because i need custom fields in url, i want to make url like this,
www.example.com/country-name/city-name/single-post-name.

Comment: Maybe with categories? I don't have a WP installation at my hands so this is just a theory.

Comment: Anyone has idea about my query, will be much appreciated if help me in my task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you require **custom permalinks.**

Using which you can **change your permalink structure** as you require with **custom fields.**

Kindly go through the following to know in depth

> http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-permalinks-in-wordpress/

Hope this helps you mate

**Edit :**

As per my suggestion htaccess is not necessary for this.

Comment: Thank you @Raja Gopal i have done it by using this plugin, actually this plugin store url as custom field with post, and then i wrote some  code, which automatically generated the url for the post while saving the post which check if the post has custom field such as city, country etc will automatically append at the end of url